# How to install USB Device Driver for LG Thrive Android Device?

Tags: usb, driver, device, android-2.2-froyo, lg

I have just purchased LG Thrive handset for android apps development purpose. I tried installing "LGMS690" and "LG _USB _Drivers_All_4.9.7" usb device drivers on my windows 7 PC, but my device is not getting detected in eclipse android plugin. I am unable to run/debug my applications on this device.
Please help me with what steps should I follow to get my device ready for running/debugging apps..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go here: http://www.lgforum.com/resources and download the Android drivers for Phoenix (basically the same phone) or use this direct link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/lgforum.com/resources/assets/680/original/LGAndroidDriver_Ver_1.0_All.zip?1304452545

I haven't tried it with the SDKs yet, but it worked for sideloading the Amazon appstore...